# How to assign different values for a variable based on content of a cell in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first time asking a question on here, so my apologies for any mistakes. I am very new to Google Scripts and am trying to write a script to automatically add up a grade based on pre-set values for different elements of it. There are three different elements (notes, review problem completeness, and review problem accuracy). For a set scale of note completeness (100%, 75%, 50%, 25%, 0+%) a value of 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 should be assigned, respectively. There are similar scales for review problem completeness and accuracy. My sheet has dropdown lists via data validation for each element, and I would like the script to begin adding up the grade as I select the level of completeness from the data validation list.

[Here is an image of the spreadsheet with dummy input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0HJ5.png)

- Lecture notes is one of 5 options: 100%, 75%, 50%, 25%, or 0%. I would like these to be associated with point values 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.
- Problem completeness is one of 4 options: 100%, 50% to 75%, 25% to 50%, and 0%. I would like these to be associated with point values 3, 2, 1, 0.
- Problem accuracy is one of 3 options: correct, partially correct, and wrong. I would like these words to be associated with point values 2, 1, 0.
- Late is a modifier, essentially. If the check box in column "Late" is checked true, I would like the sum of the points in column "Grade" to be multiplied by 0.8.

My gut instinct approach is to create a variable that takes on value 5 if completeness is 100%, value 4 if completeness if 75%, etc., but I am not entirely sure where to begin. Below is the code I have started so far:

```
SHEET_NAME = "Test";
RANGE = "B2:G36";
NOTES = "B2:B36";
PROBLEM_COMPLETENESS = "C2:C36"
PROBLEM_ACCURACY = "D2:D36";
LATE = "F2:F36";
LATE_CONDITION = true;
GRADE = "G2:G36"

function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(RANGE);
  var column = range.getColumn();

  var notes = sheet.getRange(NOTES).getValues();
  var notesscore;
  if (column==2 && notes=="100%"){notesscore = 5};
  if (column==2 && notes=="75%"){notesscore = 4};
  if (column==2 && notes=="50%"){notesscore = 3};
  if (column==2 && notes=="25%"){notesscore = 2};
  if (column==2 && notes=="0%"){notesscore = 1};

  var totalgrade = (notesscore);
  sheet.getRange(RANGE).getColumn(GRADE).setValues(totalgrade)
}
```

Any input is welcomed and I thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Any further explanation or example as to what your input is and what desired output you expect would be welcomed.

Comment: Hi, Cooper! Thanks for asking. I did link an image with an example of how the sheet is to be filled out. The inputs are the percentage scores for notes, percentage scores for problem completion, and percentage scores for problem accuracy, and I would like output to be the sum of the associated point values in the column "Grade". Each percentage "level" is assigned a point value, and I would like to sum across each row. I am still just trying to figure out where to start, so thank you for taking the time to read things over!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will work:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var notes        = { '100%': 5, '75%': 4, '50%': 3, '25%': 2, '0%': 1 };
  var completeness = { '100%': 3, '50% to 75%': 2, '25% to 50%': 1, '0%': 0 };
  var accuracy     = { 'correct': 2, 'partially correct': 1, 'wrong': 0 };

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Test') return;

  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col < 2 || col > 6) return;

  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  if (row < 2 || row > 36) return;

  var r = sheet.getRange('B' + row + ':G' + row).getValues().flat();
  var n = r[0]; // notes
  var c = r[1]; // completeness
  var a = r[2]; // accuracy

  var grade = notes[n] + completeness[c] + accuracy[a];

  var late = r[4];
  if (late) grade = grade * 0.8;

  sheet.getRange('G' + row).setValue(grade);
}
```

It will recalculate the grade in a current edited row (cell G) whenever you change something in cells B, C, D, E, F of this row. In the range from 2nd to 36th row.

And probably it makes sense for this case to use a custom formula rather than `onEdit` trigger. Not big difference, though.

Comment: Hi, Yuri! Thanks for taking the time to work on a solution. This code returns "#NUM!" in column G "Grade" (in the row the edit took place) upon edit of any column B through F, which is much further than I had gotten and pretty close to what I want! I will see if I can work with it to figure out why it is not registering the numbers, but figured I would let you know how it turned out in case you would like to also. :) Thanks again!

Comment: It's impossible to guess, since you didn't share your sheet. It works fine on my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16l1U1qQ9JZ1eWHLJAa_DJAcO0UP4Tmtcc46UYxlgAT8/edit?usp=sharing. You can copy my sheet and try to find differences.

Comment: Try to change formatting for the columns B,C,D,E into 'Plain text': https://imgur.com/Wjnmyqb.png

Comment: Yes, that solved it! Thank you again for your help.